# Android tutorial on spinner and corresponding alarm

Tags: android, android-studio, spinner, alarm

im building a drug interaction and notification application - for one section, i need to select a spinner item and then an alarm to corresspond with that spinner choice.

so far i have my code for the spinner-  the question is how to add an alarm code to corresspond to the spinner

```
public class Interactions extends Activity implements   OnItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner spinner;
    TextView showmed;
    private String[] state = {"Adalimumab",
            "Etanercept",
            "Tacrolimus",
            "Mycophenolic Acid",
            "Bicalutamide",
            "Darbepoetin alfa",
            "Ciclosporin",
            "Interferon beta-1a",
            "Triptorelin"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_interactions);
        System.out.println(state.length);
        showmed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showmed);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, state);
        adapter_state

     .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter_state);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                               long id) {

        switch(position)
        {

            case 0:
                showmed.setText("Azathioprine/cyclosporine\n" +
                        "Certain immunisupressive agents/live vacines\n" +
                        "Tumour necrosis factor blocking agents/ Abatacept\n"    
                        "Immino suppressives/ Natalizub\n");
                break;

            case 1:
                showmed.setText("Azathioprine/cyclosporine\n" +
                        "Certain immunisupressive agents/live vacines\n" +
                        "Tumour necrosis factor blocking agents/ Abatacept\n" 
                        "Immino suppressives/ Natalizub\n");
                break;

            case 2:
                showmed.setText("cyclosporine\n" +
                                "Efalizumab/Natalizumab\n" +
                                "QT Prolonging agents\n" +
                                "Mibefradil\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                showmed.setText("Questran, Welchol. Colestipol\n" +
                        "Zovirax\n" +
                        "Azathiprine\n" +
                        "Avoid antacids\n");
                break;
            case 4:
                showmed.setText("Warfine\n" +
                        "Terfenamine\n");
                break;
            case 5:
                showmed.setText("lenaliodomide\n" +
                        "pomalidomide\n" +
                        "revlimid\n" +
                        "thalimd\n");
                break;
            case 6:
                showmed.setText("birth control pills, \n" +
                        "caspofungin\n" +
                        "ezetimide\n" +
                        "sulfinpyrazone\n" +
                        "tacrolimus\n" +
                        "Drugs that weaken immune system\n" +
                        "acyclovir\n" +
                        "aminologycoside\n" +
                        "potassium supplements\n");
                break;
            case 7:
                showmed.setText("Certain immunisupressive agents/live\n"
                        "Immino suppressives/ Natalizub\n");
                break;
            case 8:
                showmed.setText("promethazine");

                break;
            case 9:
                showmed.setText("No Test done");





        }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: sorry the question is how to add an alarm code to corresspond to the spinner